# Error in insertion urdu data in php Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem to insert urdu news in mysql data_base using PHP.
**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="">
<textarea name="content">Insert news article here.</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

**php**

```
$content = $_POST['content']; $queryNews = "INSERT INTO yob_news (title, content, date) VALUES('$title','$content','$date')";
mysql_query($queryNews);
```

**After insertion**
[image]
Already add `<meta http-equiv=”Content-Type” content=”text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>`

[image]

Comment: Nice `SQL Injection` :D and `mysql_`! I would recommend you `PDO` or `mysqli_`

Comment: Question is not about SQL injection @Rizier123

Comment: Try `mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");` and also echo `$_POST['content'];` before you insert it and post what you get

Comment: I already try `mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'"); ` and `echo` the `POST` text is alright but in database same problem occur

Comment: Also try this: `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");` or `ini_set("default_charset", "UTF-8");` or it could be this `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');` and as i said please post what you get if you echo `$_POST['content'];`

Comment: Thank you @Rizier123 `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");` work greatly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64272/discussion-between-adeel-gill-and-rizier123).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work for you:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

otherwise you can try these ones out:

```
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");
mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");
ini_set("default_charset", "UTF-8");
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```