# How to insert urdu data in mysql using php script?

Tags: php

I have alot of data in urdu and I want to store in in database using php script. Someone please help me.
I have tried all these things  , mysqli_set_charset($link,"utf8"); and also change the collation to   utf8_general_ci but its not working.

Comment: My question is different!!

Comment: @AshnaAli your question could be duplicate so provide some code example this can help resolving your issue

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me from your question where your problem lies: is it that your MYSQL tables are not in UTF8, or is it that your Urdu data is not in UTF8?

To create a MYSQL table in UTF8, use a CREATE statement such as:

```
  CREATE TABLE tableName (
      col1 INT,
      (etc.)
  ) DEFAULT CHARSET utf8;
```

To alter an existing table, use an UPDATE command such as

```
  ALTER TABLE tab CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

see also this answer: [How to change all the tables in my database to UTF8 character set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150256/how-to-change-all-the-tables-in-my-database-to-utf8-character-set)

Or, for more ways of changing the MYSQL encoding using PHP functions, see this answer: [Error in insertion urdu data in php Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26746725/error-in-insertion-urdu-data-in-php-mysql?rq=1)

To convert PHP strings to UTF8 if you don't know your encoding, see this answer: [PHP: Convert any string to UTF-8 without knowing the original character set, or at least try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979567/php-convert-any-string-to-utf-8-without-knowing-the-original-character-set-or)